# Llamar a TabBarController desde un botón de un ViewController Swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode

estoy intentado llamar a un TabBarController en Swift 5 pero tengo unos problemas en la manera que se visualiza. Espero alguien pueda ayudarme. Con este código logro llamar al TabController, pero la manera en la que se presenta no es lo que busco.

Código:

```
let mainTabController=storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: 
"MainTabBarController") as! UITabBarController
        present(mainTabController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

De este modo no funciona:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainTabController, animated: true) - (de este modo ni siquiera abre el TabController)
```

[image: Error]
[image: Storyboard]

Comment: Como quieres que se visualice?

Comment: Logre lo que necesitaba, el problema era que la vista no estaba configurada en Full Screen. El código que use fue: mainTabController.modalPresentationStyle = .fulScreen

Comment: También puedes hacerlo directamente desde el storyboard, si marcas el Segue como "Over Full Screen" en lugar de "Present Modally"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La jerarquía que has empleado para manejar la navegación de tus vistas no es la correcta. No te recomiendo que instancies la vista del TabBarController por código, más abajo te explico como lo puedes hacer desde el Storyboard.

Aprovecho para explicarte porque cuando intentas hacer un push al TabBarController de esta forma no funciona.

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainTabController, animated: true)
```

Básicamente, se debe a que `self.navigationController?` es nil. No existe un NavigationController porque el ViewController no está conectado o no pertenece a una navegación.

Siempre tienes que conectar tu vista inicial con un `UINavigationController`, con esto, todas las vistas que presentes a partir del root estarán conectadas, creando así un stack de navegación. Ahora, si también vas a usar un `UITabBarController` solo debes hacerle un **Push** y listo.

Esta imagen lo explica bastante bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]